# Explode multiple array of struct in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Explode an array of struct in hive is done by below syntax.

```
col1  col2     col3   col4
A1    29      [{"M1":"P1","M2":"-1","M3":"22","M4":"0"},{"M1":"PE","M2":"136","M3":"95","M4":"0.25"}] [{"M5":"10","M6":1},{"M5":"11","M6":2}]
A2    2       [{"M1":"P1","M2":"-1","M3":"10","M4":"-0.13"}]      [{"M5":"5","M6":1}]
A3    6       NULL    NULL
A4    2       NULL    NULL
A5    3       NULL    NULL


select 
col1,
col2,
explode_col3.M1,
explode_col3.M2,
explode_col3.M3,
explode_col3.M4
from table1
LATERAL VIEW explode(col3) exploded_table as explode_col3;
```

How to explode multiple arrays col3, col4?

col3 & col4 is an array which will have equal number of records. In the below scenario first row has 2 records inside col3 & col4, where as second row
has 1 record inside col3 & col4. The first record in col3 is mapped to first record in col4, similarly for others.

Output is something:

```
col1 col2  M1       M2       M3      M4      M5      M6
A1    29    P1      -1       22      0       10      1
A1    29    PE      136      95      0.25    11      2
A2    2     P1      -10      10     -0.13    5       1
A3    6   
A4    2 
A5    3
```

Comment: are col3,col4 an array of structs or array of maps?

Comment: array of structs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are an array of structs, you can use `lateral view` in conjunction with `inline`.

```
select col1,col2,v1,v2,v3,v4--,v5,v6
from tablename
lateral view inline(col3) t1 as m1,v1,m2,v2,m3,v3,m4,v4
--lateral view inline(col4) t2 as m5,v5,m6,v6
```

Using `inline` multiple struct of array columns leads to an output like cross join, hence it is commented out.